# TypeScript unit testing cannot use import statement outside of a module

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, unit-testing

Guys, I'm following this [Link](https://medium.com/swlh/typescript-unit-testing-with-test-coverage-2cc0cc6f3fd1) to learn how to unit test in TypeScript.
Followed exactly that but running npm test generates this error:

[Error print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaCEc.png)

My code is as follow:

---- Normal constructor ----

```
export class Cliente {

    payment_method: String;

    constructor(payment_method: String) {
        this.payment_method = payment_method;
    }
}
```

---- Test ----

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { Cliente } from '../src/client';

let payment_method: String = 'paypal';

it('constructorTest', () => {
        let clientObj = new Cliente(payment_method);
        expect(clientObj.payment_method).to.be('paypal');
    })
```

---- TS Config and Package.json ----

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es2015"
    }
  }
```

```
{
  "name": "testTS",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env TS_NODE_FILES=true mocha — exit — require ts-node/register — colors test/**/*.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.18",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I have already tried some of the solutions out there but nothing solves this. Its probably something easy that I'm overlooking and cant seem to fix!

Would appreciate any help.